# Comparing two different data with time stamp

Tags: google-sheets, timestamp, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc, data-comparison

I am facing a big problem with comparing two data. One reads me data with timestamp every 1 sec and another gives me data every 2 Sec. I am confused how could I compare both data by making the data aligned to their respective timestamp.
Both are on different spreadsheets.

I tried to remove every alterative cells. But I have a load ton of data. Is there any way I could compare them

Image 1

[image: 1]

Image 2

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you pretend to compare, but you can filter by odd or even number of rows. For example:

```
=FILTER(A:Z,ISODD(ROW(A:A)))
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a good way to find out, but is there a way where I can compare the time stamp of both sheets and match them and bring the data respectively?

Comment: Yes, but you should define how you would match. In your second image, the measurements occur at irregular times. There are rows with consecutive seconds, but some with repeated "odd" values (that won't match exactly with your always "even" seconds from Image 1)

Comment: When there's not an exact match in times, should it take the next smaller or the next larger?, or not take any?